# Getting information whether a google search results exists or not (JAVA)

Tags: java, parsing, google-search

i try parsing google for search results. What i need are not the search results themselves, but instead i need the information whether a search result exists or not!

Now my problem is i want to search for combined strings. E.g. "Max Testperson".
Now google is really nice and tells me:
We could not find search results for "Max Testperson" but instead for Max Testperson. But !!! I do not need Max Testperson, i need "Max Testperson".

So basically i am not interested in the search results themselves, but instead into the part before the search results (Whether a search string can be found or not!).

I used the following tutorial in java:
http://mph-web.de/web-scraping-with-java-top-10-google-search-results/

With this i can parse the search results. But like i said! No need for that! I just want to know if my search string exists or not. Since google removes the ->" "<- i get search results anyways.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Maybe it's worth to have a look at [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/).

Comment: You should give a better test-case, since there are search results for "Max Testperson". "Max Testprson" for example gives a good example of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the get parameter `nfpr=1` to your search to disable the auto-correction feature:

```
final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://google.com/search?q=test"+"&nfpr=1").userAgent(USER_AGENT).get();
```

Update:

You could parse for the message regarding no result:

```
public class App {
    public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String searchTerm = "\"daniel+nasseh\"+\"26.02.1987\"";
        boolean hasExactResults = true;

        final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://google.com/search?q=" + searchTerm + "&nfpr=1")
                .userAgent(USER_AGENT).get();

        Elements noResultMessage = doc.select("div.e.obp div.med:first-child");

        if (!noResultMessage.isEmpty()) {

            hasExactResults = false;

            for (Element result : noResultMessage) {
                System.out.println(result.text());
            }
        }

        if (hasExactResults) {
            // Traverse the results
            for (Element result : doc.select("h3.r a")) {

                final String title = result.text();
                final String url = result.attr("href");

                System.out.println(title + " -> " + url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**: best solution as presented from Donselm himself in the comments is to add `&tbs=li:1` to force the search for the exact search term

```
String searchTerm = "\"daniel+nasseh\"+\"26.02.1987\"";

final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://google.com/search?q=" + searchTerm + "&tbs=li:1").userAgent(USER_AGENT).get();
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your Feedback. Unfortunately it seems as it does not work. Even if i add "&nfpr=1", i still get the suggestion and results for the search term without quotations.

Comment: Ok i think i could solve it by myself :-) => this one did the trick "&tbs=li:1"

Comment: ah, nice find, simpler than my fix.